# Vertical Scroll Parent on ionicScroll

Tags: ionic-framework

This is going to be a bit hard to explain but ill do my best. I'm working on an ionic project, i have on the home screen several horizontal scrolling divs, and whole view is vertically scrollable. The problem is if i drag the screen, and start initially dragging from the items  in the horizontal list, i cant vertically drag the whole view, which makes sense, cause the horizontal list has only the ionic scroll direction set to x.

But I want to mimic the effect on the facebook timeline, where there are the suggested apps ads, you can horizontally scroll through them, however if u dragged vertically u will scroll the whole timeline as normal.

[image]